# How can i check my battery status in tablet

Tags: python, pyqt4

Here, in my sample program I want to check the battery status for tablet, I tried few examples. But I did not get the proper output. When I run  this code in system it is giving correct output but when I run the same code in tablet i a getting an attribute error. So, can any one please guide me how can I check my battery in status in tablet.

My sample code:

```
def batteryStatus(self):
        battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
        try:
            plugged = battery.power_plugged
        except:
            plugged = None
        percent = int(battery.percent)
        remaining = str((100 - percent)) + ("%  remaining to charge")
        #print percent
        if percent == 100:
            self.percentLbl.setText("100 %")
        else:
            self.percentLbl.setText(str(percent) + "%")
```

Comment: What attribute? Could be python installation difference.

Comment: non type object has no attribute 'percent'

Comment: So `psutil.sensors_battery()` returns `None`.
Does `psutil` support your tablet OS?

Comment: when i  import the psutil in my tablet i didn't get any error

Comment: Well, you got `None`. Look into it.